# how to get the xml node?

Tags: java, android

Below is my xml this will be in a folder in the device and I will read the xml file. how to get/read or return the xml node in android using  XmlPullParser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appLayouts>
    <AIRLINE_FORM sendSelectionEvent="false">
        <RESULT multiSelect="false"></RESULT>
    </AIRLINE_FORM>
    <ALLOWANCES_FORM sendTableEditEvent="false" sendSelectionEvent="true">
        <RESULT multiSelect="false">
            <field header="Category" size="75" align="left" edit="false"></field>
            <field header="Allowance" size="-1" align="left" edit="false"></field>
       </RESULT>
    </ALLOWANCES_FORM>
</appLayouts>
```

So if I got  AIRLINE_FORM as a xml node I want to return the full xml node of only the AIRLINE_FORM ie it must return:

```
<AIRLINE_FORM sendSelectionEvent="false">
    <RESULT multiSelect="false"></RESULT>
</AIRLINE_FORM>
```

I tried this

```
public String parseXML(String sTargetName)
{
    String XmlNode = "";
    try {
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name;
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals(sTargetName)) {
                        XmlNode = parser.getText();
                        //parser.getAttributeValue(null,"id");
                        Log.d("Task2/Parser", "Start tag: "+parser.getName());

                        Log.d("Task2/Parser", "Start tag -text: "+parser.getText());
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    Log.d("Task2/Parser", "End tag: "+parser.getName());
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    Log.d("Task2/Parser", "Text "+parser.getText());

            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    }catch (XmlPullParserException ex){
        //AppLog.WriteMessage(AppLog.LogType.ERROR, ex.Message);
        Log.d("Log_d"," Exception: "+ ex.toString());
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        //AppLog.WriteMessage(AppLog.LogType.ERROR, ex.Message);
        Log.d("Log_d"," Exception: "+ ex.toString());
    }
    return XmlNode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **pass Node Name** of each node you want to access. Here is code that will help you to obtain node

```
public String getValue(Element item, String str) {      
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I may, I suggest you use `DOM4J` xml parser. Once you have parsed your xml data, getting to your node can be as simple as:

```
xml.selectSingleNode("./AIRLINE_FORM");
```

This saves you from iterations required by `XMLPullParser`.

Here is my working code using `DOM4J`:

1) Create the file parser:

```
public class XMLUtil {
    public static Node parseFile(InputStream is) {
        Node retData = null;
        SAXReader xmlReader = new SAXReader();
        try {
            Document document = xmlReader.read(is);
            retData = document.getRootElement();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retData;
    }
}
```

2) Extract what you need by simply specifying the path to your node (sample usage: `getNodeFromPath("./AIRLINE_FORM")`):

```
private Node getNodeFromPath(String path) {
    Node retData = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = getAssets().open("filename.xml");
        Node xml = XMLUtil.parseFile(is);
        retData = xml.selectSingleNode(path);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(is != null) is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return retData;
}
```

Note that in "./AIRLINE_FORM", the "." is your root tag ("appLayouts").

Cheers!